# PHP script giving false results

Tags: php

The script:

```
<?php
    $dir = 'http://www.example.com/';
    $page = '
        <script src="folder/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="folder/script.js"></script>';
    $last = $data = $property = 0;
    //search for all script tags
    while (($last = stripos($page, '<script', $property))!==false) {
        //find src property
        $property = stripos($page, 'scr', $last);
        if ($property===false && $property > $last+50) continue;
        //find the start of the address
        $data = stripos($page, '"', $property) + 1;
        if ($data===false && $data > $prop+5) continue;
        if (substr($page, $data, 4) !== 'http') {
            $page = substr($page, 0, $data) . $dir . substr($page, $data);
        }
    }
    echo $page;
?>
```

output:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/folder/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="http://www.example.com/text/javascript" src="folder/script.js"></script>
```

Why is it inserting $dir after the first ("), not after the (") of src attribute?

Comment: You have a typo in there: **scr** instead of **src** in `$property = stripos($page, 'scr', $last);` .. Just sayin'

Comment: `$last = $data = $property = 0;` <= can you do that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, why not? I suggest you read the manual...

Comment: @OIS I will, thanks. Like Ansel Adams was a photographic genius/master, thought of himself as a "student" of the "art" ;-) cheers

Comment: if ($property===false && $property > $last+50) continue; <- This will never be true. It can be reduced to: if (0 > 50)

Comment: @Smuuf thanks, I was "hitting my head on the wall" trying to solve this;

Comment: @Wesley Murch yes, I know it is not a good way, it is because I insert $dir for every occurrence separately. my was to find all places where I should put it, then just put it all in at the same time. what was your idea?

Comment: @OIS I'll change the if statement, it should have been || (or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex:

```
$dir = 'http://www.example.com/';
$page = '
    <script src="folder/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="folder/script.js"></script>';
$regex = '#(<script .*src=")#';
$replace = '\1\2' . $dir;
$page = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $page);
echo htmlspecialchars($page);
```

Result:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/folder/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/folder/script.js"></script>
```